# Testing granite-ink WebComponents element using Selenium WebdriverJS

Tags: html, selenium, automated-tests, web-component

I have the following html code using the granite-ink WebComponents element:

```
<granite-ink id="graniteSignature" class="style-scope signature-control">

    <div id="inputArea" class="style-scope granite-ink" style="touch-action: 
none;"><canvas width="887" height="112"></canvas></div>
  </granite-ink>
```

the code that I tried to test it using Selenium are:

```
var canvas = drawing.findElement(webdriver.By.css("#inputArea"));
var actions = driver.actions();
actions.mouseMove(canvas,500,100).mouseDown().mouseMove(canvas,200,60).mouseUp().perform();
```

When I run it on my cmd, nothing happens on the signature canvas area in my app, anyone know how can I amend that? I also found that I can't use clickandHold() and some other Seleium methods in my test.

Comment: Technically the `#inputArea` element is the container `DIV`. Have you tried `#inputArea > canvas` to get the `CANVAS` tag itself?

Answer (score 0):

To identify the `<canvas>` element instead of using the `css` as `#inputArea` you can use the following line of code :

```
var canvas = drawing.findElement(webdriver.By.css("granite-ink.style-scope.signature-control#graniteSignature > div.style-scope.granite-ink#inputArea > canvas"));
```